# where can I download source code for asp.net mvc 5.2.2 version (alone)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I go to https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc, it shows the very latest.

Neither I could get from here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

If I need source code for any asp.net mvc version, where do I find it (especially for downloading/debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can easily download

git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/aspnetwebstack.git

Comment: I did that and it takes forever...not sure if it's normal

Comment: Thanks for the clue.  Finally got it at : https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/tree/v3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The current location is https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack.git

i.e. `git clone https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack.git`